# C# tasks are not cancelled

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have several tasks to execute. Each task completes its execution in different duration. Some of the tasks perform database access, some of them just makes some calculations. My code has the following structure:

```
var Canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();

List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 3); return 3; }, Canceller.Token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 1); return 1; }, Canceller.Token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 2); return 2; }, Canceller.Token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(8000); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 8); return 8; }, Canceller.Token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(6000); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 6); return 6; }, Canceller.Token));

tasks.ForEach(x => x.Start());

bool Result = Task.WaitAll(tasks.Select(x => x).ToArray(), 3000);

Console.WriteLine(Result);

Canceller.Cancel();

tasks.ToList().ForEach(x => { x.Dispose(); }); // Exception here
tasks.Clear();
tasks = null;

Canceller.Dispose();
Canceller = null;
```

I have a period of 5 seconds to start all these tasks. In every 5 seconds I call the code above. Before the next call I have to be sure that no task remains from the previous execution period. Let's say if 3 seconds are passed after the execution I would like to cancel execution of tasks which are not completed.

when I run the code `Task.WaitAll` parameter of 3000 lets first 3 tasks are completed as expected. Then I get `Result` as `false` because 2 other tasks are not completed. Then I must cancel these two tasks. If I try to dispose them I get exception saying "Tasks in completed state can only be disposed."

How can I achieve this? After I call `Cancel` method of `CancellationTokenSource` these two tasks are still executed. What is wrong here?

Comment: Split job (`Sleep(8000)`) into pieces (`Sleep(100) * 80`) and check for [`IsCancelationRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) before starting each piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should almost never use `Task.Start`. Use the static `Task.Run` method instead.

When you pass a `CancellationToken` to `Task.Run` or other APIs that create tasks, this does not allow you to abort the task immediately by requesting cancellation. This just only sets the status of the task to `Canceled` if the code in the task throws a `OperationCanceledException` exception. Please take a look at the CancellationToken section of [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html).

To cancel a task, the code that the task runs must cooperate with you. For example, if the code does something in a loop, then that code must check periodically if cancellation is requested and throw an exception if so (or simply exit the loop if you don't want the task to be considered cancelled). There is a method in `CancellationToken` called `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` that does just that. This of course means that such code needs to have access to the `CancellationToken` object. This is why we have methods that accept cancellation tokens.

As another example, if the code that the task runs calls a database access method, you'd better call a method that accepts a `CancellationToken` so that such method will try to exit as soon as cancellation is requested.

So in summary, cancelling an operation is not a magical thing as the code that the task runs need to cooperate.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cancel the tasks that haven't yet completed, you need to do so by cooperative cancellation. Currently, none of your tasks monitor the `CancellationToken` passed to them at all.

Monitoring the token using a synchronous `Thread.Sleep` can work if you monitor the token after waking up from the sleep, not this will *not* abort any ongoing thread which is currently in a sleeping state. Instead, I provide an alternative using `Task.Delay`. This is suitable when you want to monitor on the token, as it allows you to pass the token to the delaying operation itself.

A rough sketch of an async equivalent could look like this:

```
public async Task ExecuteAndTimeoutAsync()
{
    var canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var delay = 2000;
            await Task.Delay(delay, canceller.Token);
            if (canceller.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Operation with delay of {delay} cancelled");
                return -1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 3);
            return 3;
        }, canceller.Token),
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var delay = 5000;
            await Task.Delay(, canceller.Token);
            if (canceller.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Operation with delay of {delay} cancelled");
                return -1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 2);
            return 2;
        }, canceller.Token)
    };

    await Task.Delay(3000);
    canceller.Cancel();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

If using async isn't possible, consider monitoring on the given token *after* using `Thread.Sleep`, so your thread knows you actually requested a cancellation.

Side Note:

1. Use `Task.Run` instead of `new Task`. The former returns a "hot task" which has already started, no need to iterate the collection and call `Start`.
2. There is really no need to dispose the `Task`. Use it only if you use the `WaitHandle` exposed by the `Task`, which you're not using here
3. Do prefer using `Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`.
4. Do follow .NET naming conventions in your code.

Comment: your example is technically correct but the amount of code looks terrible and begs for a function

Comment: @StenPetrov It does, but this is a quick and dirty copy-and-correct. I'm not going to re-implement this method for him, as it seems mainly like test and throw away code. If this is anything that's going to production, a definite code review is in order. But, the purpose of my answer is to convey the technical way of doing this, not the proper way to implement multiple task execution.

Comment: Replacing `Thread.Sleep` with `Task.Delay(..., token)` is like a cheat. Can you make this working with `Thread.Sleep` (which is a synchronous method what doesn't support cancellation)? I am trying to figure out if my comment to question make sense.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm not sure what you mean by cheat, this is de-facto way of asynchronously yielding control for a certain time period. I see no need to start a thread and then actively blocking it.

Comment: So this will not work with `Sleep`. Still has same problem as OP example as I see it. You simply *solved* OP snippet issue (by replacing synchronous code with asynchronous) and poorly explained it (though @YacoubMassad answer explains it enough). This is not always possible (replacing something with asynchronous method which by miracle also supports cancellation), therefore my comments.

Comment: @Sinatr OP can switch `Task.Delay` with `Thread.Sleep`. The difference will be in the fact that forcing his thread to sleep will only allow him to monitor the token cancellation after that thread wakes up. Switching to `Task.Delay` does exactly what the OP wants, it allows cooperative cancellation even during execution halt. If you think my question is poorly explained, you're more than welcome to add your own answer and elaborate on how you think his code should be. Answering doesn't always mean solving the problem the exact same way the OP wrote his code.

Comment: @Sinatr Sometimes, providing an *alternative solution* is suitable as well, as I find with this answer. I have modified the answer now to include my train of thought, perhaps you'll find it better explained now.

Answer (score 1):

In the Task classes, cancellation involves cooperation between the user delegate, which represents a cancelable operation and the code that requested the cancellation.  A successful cancellation involves the requesting code calling the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method, and the user delegate terminating the operation in a timely manner. You can terminate the operation by using one of these options:

- By simply returning from the delegate. In many scenarios this is sufficient; however, a task instance that is canceled in this way transitions to the `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` state, not to theTaskStatus.Canceled state.
- By throwing a `OperationCanceledException` and passing it the token on which cancellation was requested. The preferred way to do this is to use the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method. A task that is canceled in this way transitions to the Canceled state, which the calling code can use to verify that the task responded to its cancellation request.

So, you have to listen for cancellation signal in your tasks:

```
var Canceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = Canceller.Token;

List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 3); return 3; }, token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 1); return 1; }, token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 2); return 2; }, token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(8000); token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 8); return 8; }, token));
tasks.Add(new Task<int>(() => { Thread.Sleep(6000); token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, 6); return 6; }, token));

tasks.ForEach(x => x.Start());

bool Result = Task.WaitAll(tasks.Select(x => x).ToArray(), 3000);

Console.WriteLine(Result);

Canceller.Cancel();

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    if (!(ex.InnerException is TaskCanceledException))
        throw ex.InnerException;
}

tasks.ToList().ForEach(x => { x.Dispose(); });
tasks.Clear();
tasks = null;

Canceller.Dispose();
Canceller = null;
```